# mobile first 8 console doesn't have choose platform at application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

currently i'm working with mobile first 8 and having problem in remote server deployment

in local environment(my laptop), i can show all available platform like picture below

[development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPIA4.png)

but in remote server, it only shown IOS

[remote server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pOJq.png)

can someone help me? i already run through the IBM documentation and still can't find the solution

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've installed the wrong edition of MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 on your remote server.

There are two editions:

1. The "regular" edition
2. The "iOS" edition

In the iOS edition, the console is aimed at only iOS development, and so you do not have any other platform.

Make sure you have downloaded the "regular" edition.

Comment: idan, can i confirm to you which one is the regular edition? i'm using passport advantage and i get this zip file "MFPF_8.0_IMR_MFP_SVR_MP_EN.zip".. Because this is the latest i installed in my remote server and i get IOS edition

Comment: @GarryAlfa, which version did you eventually download? What was the correct part number?